# In SDL Tridion 2011, how can I specify additional, reusable contact information in Audience Manager that must be updateable from a single location?

Tags: tridion

I have a requirement to assign additional information to multiple contacts in Audience Manager, where the same information must be reusable across all appropriate contacts, as well as being editable in a single location. This information must also be accessible using the CD APIs. How do I best go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of two possibilities:

1. **Create specific Keywords** for this shared information and assign them *en masse* to the appropriate Contacts through the Import Keywords screen. The **downside** to this approach is that it is harder to selectively remove Keywords this way (but easy to selectively add new ones). A **benefit** is that it is easily available for use on the CD side and you can easily create Dynamic Address Books / Distribution Lists / Segments using the different Keywords.
2. **Create specific Contacts** to hold this shared information and put their identification field values into an Extended Detail field for each relevant Contact. On the CD side, you would read the IDs from the Contact and load the shared information Contact separately. A **pro** for this approach is that you can easily maintain the shared information in one place and any changes you make will be picked up immediately for all of the Contacts using it. A **con** is that you need to load twice as many Contacts on the CD side.

Which one is the best approach depends on the specifics of your use case. 
Good luck with it :)

Answer (score 3):

Can you elaborate on what you want to achieve? I wonder if it could be similar to a case I ran across recently, where I really wanted to group contacts together as 'accounts'. An account could represent a company, and the contacts could represent an employee, for example.

This is simply not part of the Audience Manager data model. I guess you could hack it into the model to some extent. Peter's second suggestion would be a way to do it. However, the 'account contacts' would show up as regular contacts in the GUI, the link from the 'normal contact' to the 'account contact' would not be managed, etc.

Comment: My requirement sounds like your example. A number of contacts need to be associated with some sort of parent entity, e.g. a company. Information about the company, managed with the company entity needs to be available as part of the contact information.